# Upgrade fails with InvalidArgumentException

Tags: 9, upgrading

After upgrading from Drupal 8.9 to Drupal 9.3, I get this fatal error when I run the database updates. The remaining updates aren't executed. It looks like the Multiversion Uninstall command needs to be run, but it's not installed.

> system module - Update entity_revision_metadata_bc_cleanup
>
> Failed: InvalidArgumentException: Drupal\multiversion\Entity\Storage\Sql\ContentEntityStorage does not implement
> Drupal\Core\Entity\ContentEntityStorageInterface in
> Drupal\Core\Entity\ContentEntityType->checkStorageClass() (line 52 of public/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/ContentEntityType.php).

Comment: Is the multiversion module actually compatible with Drupal 9? It seems not.

Comment: Multiversion is not compatible with Drupal 9.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing all rows Drupal 9.3's key_value table containing 'multiversion' allowed the database update to complete successfully.

```
select * from key_value where value like '%multiversion%';

delete from key_value where value like '%multiversion%';
```